# How to parse and dump Ruby config files?

Tags: ruby, parsing, configuration, config

In [this](https://medium.com/@darrenrush/ruby-is-the-ultimate-config-file-format-615ec2a2e467) blog post he gives this example of a Ruby config file.

```
config do
 allow ['server.com', `hostname`.strip]

 vhost 'api.server.com' do
   path ‘/usr/local/api’
 end

 vhost 'www.server.com' do
   path '/usr/local/web'
 end

 %w{wiki blog support}.each do |host|
   vhost "#{host}.server.com" do
     path "/usr/local/#{host}"
   end
 end
end
```

I think of a hash after a config file have been loaded, but maybe that is not how this type of configs are intended for...

**Update**

If I execute it, I get

```
$ ruby config.rb 
config.rb:2:in `<main>': undefined method `config' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

**Question**

What Ruby code is needed to parse and dump the content of this config file?

Comment: It's just Ruby code. So they can be parsed (and executed) by the `ruby` program (as shown in the article), for example. “Dumping” can be done with [`IO.write`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-c-write) or a similar method.

Comment: @cremno I have just updated the OP with the error I get, if I try that. So I suppose I need some sort of parser?

Comment: This example code uses a [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) but you don't have its implementation (thus the `NoMethodError`). If it exists, somebody might recognize it. However I don't get why you want to do sth. with it. A popular Ruby tool with a DSL is [rake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rake_%28software%29). You could take a look at that instead if you're interested in this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That config example is not directly loadable and, if I understand the blog post author correctly, it's not meant to be either so there's no easy way of loading/parsing that example.

The key part is in the blog post where he states "build simple DSLs to design semantically robust config files without the *underlying ruby being conspicuous*" (my emphasis). The 'underlying ruby' I take to mean the code that enables the DSL elements you're seeing such as 'config' and 'vhost'.

Your original question was, however, what code is required to load that config - below is a sample of something would work, full implementation is up to you and tbh I'm pretty sure there are cleaner, "better" ways of doing the same.

```
    class AppConfig
        attr_accessor :hosts

        def allow(hosts)
            @hosts = hosts
        end

        def vhost(hostname)
        end

        def process_config(&block)
            instance_eval(&block)
        end
    end

    def config(&block)
        config = AppConfig.new
        config.process_config &block
        puts "Hosts are: #{config.hosts}"
    end


    load 'config.rb'
```

Comment: What I don't quite understand is that there is a lot more information in the config file than what is being outputted from you script. Does that mean specific code have to be written for each block in the config file? With e.g. yaml files, it is always the same 2-3 lines of code that will parse and dump any yaml file. Is that not the case with this type of config files?

Comment: I think you're suspicion is correct, in that the application developer (i.e. config file syntax/DSL writer) would have to write a class or code that implements each part of the config file DSL. As you're aware, the code I wrote there doesn't even implement all of it, I just did enough to make the sample not break (ideally I just wanted to do `allow` but it needed `vhost` too). The question really becomes: is the config format in the blog really a good idea or not? Obviously the post author thinks it is. Me, I'm unconvinced for small-scale or apps that are not re-used at lot.